# Android sensor data collection in service not working consistently with timer

Tags: android, service, timer, sensors, file-writing

So, in my Android sensor app, I have a service (foreground) which runs continuously in a different process and records separate sensors' data (accelerometer, magnetometer, GPS). I have used a timer of period 100 ms to fetch and write the data in various CSV files for different sensors. The problem is that the data recording is not consistent, i.e. the timer is not working properly or something. It skips some intervals like for few 100 ms or sometimes even few secs while it should record ten samples per second. I have defined custom classes for the sensors, and they are working properly.

Here is my code for the service:

```
package com.example.ark.ark.Services;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.example.ark.ark.Constants;
import com.example.ark.ark.R;
import com.example.ark.ark.Sensors.Accelerometer;
import com.example.ark.ark.Sensors.Gps;
import com.example.ark.ark.Sensors.Magnetometer;
import com.example.ark.ark.Sensors.Rotation;
import com.example.ark.ark.activity.MainActivity;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import static com.example.ark.ark.Constants.*;

/**
 * Created by ark on 12/8/17.
 */

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public class DataRecording extends Service {
    private Magnetometer magnetometer;
    private Accelerometer accelerometer;
    private Gps gps;
    private Rotation rot;
    private Timer myTimer, gpsTimer;
    //frequency variables
    private int acc_mag_freq = 100;
    private int gps_freq = 2000;

    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat(TIMESTAMP_FORMAT);
    SimpleDateFormat time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy_HH:mm:ss");

    //Declaring file variables
    private File sdDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + DIRECTORY);
    File accDirectory = new File(sdDirectory + Constants.DIRECTORY_ACC);
    File magDirectory = new File(sdDirectory + Constants.DIRECTORY_MAG);
    File gpsDirectory = new File(sdDirectory + Constants.DIRECTORY_GPS);
    File rotationDirectory = new File(sdDirectory + Constants.DIRECTORY_ROTATION);
    private File datafile_Rot;
    private File dataFile_Acc;
    private File dataFile_Mag;
    private File dataFile_Gps;
    private FileOutputStream dataOutputStream_Acc, dataOutputStream_Mag, dataOutputStream_Gps, dataOutputStream_Rot;

    private StringBuilder data_Acc = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder data_Mag = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder data_Gps = new StringBuilder();
    private StringBuilder data_Rot = new StringBuilder();
    private String mode = new String();
    private String acc_name, mag_name, rot_name, gps_name, user = "";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Intent notify = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notify, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icon_1_round)
                .setContentTitle("Mobility")
                .setContentText("Recording Data")
                .setContentIntent(pendingintent).build();

        startForeground(1337, notification);
        //Creating objects of the different sensor's class
        magnetometer = new Magnetometer(this);
        accelerometer = new Accelerometer(this);
        gps = new Gps(this);
        rot = new Rotation(this);

        data_Gps.append("\n");
        data_Acc.append("\n");
        if (magnetometer.isMagAvailable()) {
            data_Rot.append("\n");
            data_Mag.append("\n");
        }


        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
            user = intent.getExtras().getString("username");
            String t = intent.getExtras().getString("acc_mag_freq");
            String r = intent.getExtras().getString("gps_freq");
            mode = intent.getExtras().getString("mode");
            acc_mag_freq = Integer.parseInt(t);
            gps_freq = Integer.parseInt(r);
        }

        //Creating variables for file names
        acc_name = user + "_" + time1.format(new Date()) + "_" + Constants.DATA_FILE_NAME_ACC;
        gps_name = user + "_" + time1.format(new Date()) + "_" + Constants.DATA_FILE_NAME_GPS;
        mag_name = user + "_" + time1.format(new Date()) + "_" + Constants.DATA_FILE_NAME_MAG;
        rot_name = user + "_" + time1.format(new Date()) + "_" + Constants.DATA_FILE_NAME_ROTATION;

        dataFile_Acc = new File(accDirectory, acc_name);
        if (magnetometer.isMagAvailable()) {
            dataFile_Mag = new File(magDirectory, mag_name);
            if (mode.equals("1"))
                datafile_Rot = new File(rotationDirectory, rot_name);
        }
        dataFile_Gps = new File(gpsDirectory, gps_name);

        try {
            dataOutputStream_Acc = new FileOutputStream(dataFile_Acc, true);
            if (magnetometer.isMagAvailable()) {
                dataOutputStream_Mag = new FileOutputStream(dataFile_Mag, true);
                if (datafile_Rot != null)
                    dataOutputStream_Rot = new FileOutputStream(datafile_Rot, true);
            }

            dataOutputStream_Gps = new FileOutputStream(dataFile_Gps, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myTimer = new Timer();
        myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getDataSensors();
            }

        }, 0, acc_mag_freq);
        gpsTimer = new Timer();
        gpsTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getDataGps();
            }
        }, 0, gps_freq);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void getDataGps() {
        data_Gps.append(time.format(new Date()));
        data_Gps.append(",");
        float[] gpsreading = gps.getReading();
        data_Gps.append(String.format("%.10f", gpsreading[0]));
        data_Gps.append(",");
        data_Gps.append(String.format("%.10f", gpsreading[1]));
        data_Gps.append("\n");
        try {
              dataOutputStream_Gps.write(data_Gps.toString().getBytes());

            data_Gps.setLength(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getDataSensors() {
        data_Acc.append(time.format(new Date()));
        data_Acc.append(",");
        if (magnetometer.isMagAvailable()) {
            data_Mag.append(time.format(new Date()));
            data_Mag.append(",");
            if (mode == "1") {
                data_Rot.append(time.format(new Date()));
                data_Rot.append(",");
            }
        }
        float[] acc = accelerometer.getLastReading();
        float[] mag = magnetometer.getLastReading();
        float[] rotVal = rot.getLastReading();
        //accelerometer data_Acc
        data_Acc.append(String.format("%.3f", acc[0]));
        data_Acc.append(",");
        data_Acc.append(String.format("%.3f", acc[1]));
        data_Acc.append(",");
        data_Acc.append(String.format("%.3f", acc[2]));
        //data_Acc.append(",");
        if (magnetometer.isMagAvailable()) {
            //magnetometer data_Acc
            data_Mag.append(String.format("%.3f", mag[0]));
            data_Mag.append(",");
            data_Mag.append(String.format("%.3f", mag[1]));
            data_Mag.append(",");
            data_Mag.append(String.format("%.3f", mag[2]));
            //data_Acc.append(",");
            // write this data_Acc to file
            data_Mag.append("\n");
            if (mode == "1") {
                data_Rot.append(String.format("%.3f", rotVal[0]));
                data_Rot.append(",");
                data_Rot.append(String.format("%.3f", rotVal[1]));
                data_Rot.append(",");
                data_Rot.append(String.format("%.3f", rotVal[2]));
                //data_Acc.append(",");
                // write this data_Acc to file
                data_Rot.append("\n");
            }
        }
        data_Acc.append("\n");
        try {

            dataOutputStream_Acc.write(data_Acc.toString().getBytes());
            if (magnetometer.isMagAvailable()) {
                dataOutputStream_Mag.write(data_Mag.toString().getBytes());
                if (mode == "1") {
                    dataOutputStream_Rot.write(data_Rot.toString().getBytes());
                }
            }
            data_Acc.setLength(0);
            data_Rot.setLength(0);
            data_Mag.setLength(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you acquire partial_lock? https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html If you screen gets locked, the cpu goes to sleep. For that, you need to acquire the partial lock.

Comment: If these delays are not frequent then it is also normal because timer does not guarantee the exact time interval. Let's say if you ask it to fire every 20 milliseconds, it won't fire all the time exactly at that interval as it depends on CPU load and what else is going on in the device.

Comment: Such behavior causes a delay of a few milliseconds. It is usually acceptable delay for activity recognition for example. If its frequently happening then use the partial lock.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know Android is not designed to support hard real time events, so I don't think you can achieve that in any way.

Anyway I think you could try using [alarms](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) and defining the service as a [foreground service](http://www.truiton.com/2014/10/android-foreground-service-example/), if you can use these things in your app, from what I know it won't ensure that data retrieval is executed every 100 ms, but it's likely to do it on a more regular basis.

Comment: I am using foreground service only.